# Debugging a Unit Test Does Not Execute a Certain Method

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have a test method which when called should return a string.

```
private Mock<API> _api;
private Mock<IResponseHelper> _responseHelper;
private Logic _logic;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    _api = new Mock<API>();
    _responseHelper = new Mock<IResponseHelper>();
}

[Test]
[TestCase(HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[TestCase(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public void Method2_WhenCalled_ReturnAString(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode)
{
    _api.Setup(api => api.Method1(new List<string> { "a" }, "a"))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = httpStatusCode, Content = new StringContent("") }));

    _responseHelper.Setup(rh => rh.JsonPrettyPrint(
            It.IsAny<HttpResponseMessage>(),
            It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(It.IsAny<string>());

    _logic = new Logic(_api.Object, _responseHelper.Object);

    var result = _logic.Method2(new List<string> { "a" }, "a");

    Assert.That(result, Is.TypeOf<string>());
}
```

Now when I run this test the test runner will state that the expected result should be a `string`, however it returned `null`. So when I debugged the method under test (`_logic.Method2()`) it does not go inside the ResponseHelper method even if I press F11.

```
public string Method2(List<string> ids, string groupId)
{
    var result = _api.Method1(ids, groupId)
                     .Result;

    var prettyString = _responseHelper.JsonPrettyPrint(
        result, 
        "Some random string."); // If I try to press F11 at this point it does not step inside the JsonPrettyPrint method and instead just returns a null value. 

    return prettyString 
}
```

Is there anything wrong with how I setup my test method?

Comment: As far as I can see you should be writing the actual string that it returns in the Returns call on the _responseHelper instead of It.IsAny<string>().

Comment: I tried it and it worked. The `_responseHelper` is supposed to return an empty string as the actual result based on my setup. Isn't `string.Empty` - which basically translates to `""` - equal to `It.IsAny<string>()`?

Comment: @JoshMonreal No. `It.IsAny<string>()` is only meant to be used in the setup expression. No where else. It will return null when used outside of setup expression.